# Recebendo dados de um observable

Tags: javascript, array, angular

Estou com um problema ao usar um Observable. Enquanto estou dentro do método NgOinit, ao buscar os dados, recebo o array  corretamente e seto na variável da classe. Entretanto, ao tentar acessar os dados fora do subscribe, recebo undefined como resposta. Alguém sabe dizer porque isso ocorre?

```
@Component({
      moduleId: module.id,
      selector: 'operacao',
      templateUrl: './operacao.component.html',
      providers: [Operacao],
      styleUrls: ['./operacao.component.css']
    })
    export class OperacaoComponent implements OnInit {

      private _operacao: Operacao;
      private _operacoes: any[];


    public rows: Array<any> = [];
    private myserviceService: MyserviceService;
...


 constructor(myservice: MyserviceService) {
    this.length = 10;
    this.myserviceService = myservice;

  }
    ...

ngOnInit() {
 this.myserviceService.getOperacoes()
  .subscribe((operacao) => {
    this._operacoes = operacao; 
    //here i get the "right" value
     console.log(this._operacoes); 
    //Array(2) [Object, Object]
    //0:Object {id: 0, acao_id: 0, user_id: "1", …}
    //1:Object {id: 1, acao_id: 1, user_id: "1", …}
```

myservice.ts

```
getOperacoes() {
      return this.http.get(this.url + 'operacoes').map(res => res.json());
}
```

quando tento acessar os dados fora do observable, recebo undefined.

```
console.log(this._operacoes);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que você está usando a palavra reservada `this` para acessar a variável operações dentro do subscribe.
Isso acontece, porque em javascript, o [escopo do `this` muda quando você entra no bloco da `function` que você criou](http://www.abequar.net/posts/entendendo-javascript-escopo-e-a-palavra-chave-this) para o subscribe.

Para resolver esse problema, precisamos atrelar o this do escopo da sua classe principal a uma variável e passá-la **dentro** do subscribe. Para isso, basta alterar o seu `ngOnInit` para:

```
ngOnInit() {
 let self = this;
 this.myserviceService.getOperacoes()
  .subscribe((operacao) => {
    self._operacoes = operacao; 
     console.log(self._operacoes);
  });
}
```

Caso você tenha só uma linha (uma atribuição, por exemplo), você não precisaria criar um novo bloco (consequentemente, você não criaria um novo escopo), podendo, assim, utilizar a palavra chave `this`, da seguinte forma:

```
ngOnInit() {
 this.myserviceService.getOperacoes()
  .subscribe((operacao) => this._operacoes = operacao);
}
```

Um terceira possibilidade é atrelar uma `function` da própria classe para ela fazer o tratamento dos dados recebidos, da seguinte forma:

```
ngOnInit() {
 this.myserviceService.getOperacoes()
  .subscribe((operacao) => this.trataResposta(operacao));
}

trataResposta(resposta: any[]) {
  this._operacao = resposta;
  //Qualquer tratamento necessário
}
```

Comment: Felipe, obrigado pela resposta.

Comment: @tecnocrata, se a resposta resolveu o seu problema, pode aceitá-la, por favor?

Comment: Desculpe, achei que tinha aceitado-a. Entretanto, debugando o problema...verifiquei q nao era no observable (ao criar um html teste, com databinding os dados foram exibidos normalmente) e sim no module (ng-table) que uso. Creio que terei q alterar o método onChangeTable usado pelo módulo. De toda forma, sua resposta me levou ao caminho correto! Grato!